# How to use "Instance ID" in cloud-config.yml on CoreOS on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, coreos, cloud-init

I have CoreOS instances on Amazon EC2.

There are some pre-defined variables accessible from cloud-config.yml such as "$private_ipv4" or "$public_ipv4".

Is there a way to access "Instance ID" of EC2 instances like "$instance_id"?
(I have tried "$instance_id" and "$INSTANCE_ID" but neither of them took effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That variable isn't built in, but you could do one of two things:

1. curl the metadata service for that value directly:

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

2. have a "oneshot" unit write out a the result of that curl to a file and then source that file in your units, just like you can for environment info.

The oneshot unit one would write `INSTANCE_ID=abc123` to `/etc/instance-id` and your regular unit would depend on the oneshot (`Requires=instanceid.service`/`After=instanceid.service`) contains `EnvironmentFile=/etc/instance-id`, which would make $INSTANCE_ID available for use in a unit.

More docs on using env vars in units: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html#environmentfile-directive

Comment: Thank you Rob!

It really helps :-)

Comment: I'm confused by this. The cloudinit docs seem to say differently. http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#run-commands-on-first-boot

Comment: Also: http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#call-a-url-when-finished

Comment: In practice I have the same issue. $INSTANCE_ID does not seem to be defined.

Comment: CoreOS' version of cloud-init only supports a subset of the entire cloud-init spec. The only variables that are supported are the IP addresses.